# Jenkins - iOS - pack to IPA error

Tags: ios, jenkins, automation, devops

I am able to build and archive with Jenkins, but when I try to pack,  build and sign to .ipa I get errors.

Jenkins relevant logs :

```
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app' were found
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS Ad Hoc provisioning profiles matching 'com.globekeeper.app'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.Widget' were found
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.Widget' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.Widget' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS Ad Hoc provisioning profiles matching 'com.globekeeper.app.Widget'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.ShareExtension' were found
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.ShareExtension' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.globekeeper.app.ShareExtension' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS Ad Hoc provisioning profiles matching 'com.globekeeper.app.ShareExtension'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

any help will be appreciated.